# Hugo data files from dynamic parameter

Tags: go, yaml, templating, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm developing a big hugo template. I try to simplfy the problem, so I have two datafile:

- PROMO_00_1.yaml
- PROMO_00_2.yaml

that are phisically stored in this directory:

themes/data/hp/

So, in the site config the user will decide which of this data file will be used simply indicate it in a param (HpElement).

In the template I call the partial in this way:

```
 {{ partial "multiplepages/homepage/promos/00_promo_singleslide_text_video" (dict "context" . "data" $.Site.Params.HpElement) }}
```

In a partial I write:

```
{{ $data_partial := (printf "$.Site.Data.homepage.%s" .data)}}
{{ $data_partial}}
```

and the Hugo output is on the website:

```
$.Site.Data.homepage.PROMO_00_1
```

What I need is to access the single variable inside the .yaml file but the user MUST can decide which YAML file have to use. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just finished up a similar use case where I needed to select a YAML based on a date stamp. The **index** function is key to this operation.

https://gohugo.io/functions/index-function/

Here is a simplified version of my situation:

```
{{ $date := now.Format "s20060102"}}
{{ $data := (index .Site.Data.schedule $date) }}

{{ with $data }}
  <h1>.longdate</h1>
  {{ range .times }}
    <h2>{{ .name }} - {{ .location }}
  {{ end}
{{ end}
```

The example in the Hugo documentation uses an example where the data file is selected based on an attribute in the front matter.